# Bluetooth is nonexistant on my laptop?[Fixed]

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

I just reinstalled windows 10 because it was slow and needed a fresh start. Everything went fine but now bluetooth doesn't seem to exist. There are no options for it and in device manager there is no place I can see it. I have had to write this all with the on-screen keyboard because my keyboard in my laptop isn't working. Oh and bluetooth worked before I reinstalled Windows 10.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Inspiron 3541

Fix: Downloaded the program Driver Talent and it showed that my Bluetooth was having issues. Thankfully their Pro is free right now so it fixed the (drivers? idk what was really wrong) and now it is working. Thanks for the comments trying to help!

Comment: What is the make and model of your Laptop?

Comment: Like I put in the description Inspiron 3541

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question & type 'fixed' in the title. That helps no-one. Post an actual answer & mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Prompt and enter this command:

> set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1

Then go to Device Manager (right click on Computer -> Manage), click View and select "Show hidden devices". You should then be able to see your Bluetooth device.

Comment: Nope, it didnt show me anything new.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on your user name in Device Manager and selecting "Scan for hardware changes"? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753699(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try these

- Check all your drivers are up to date here: 
  http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3541-laptop/drivers
- Also ensure Bluetooth is turned on in your BIOS settings.
- Is your wireless enabled and working?